# How to do operator overloading

Tags: c++

How do I write a program to overload the + operator so that it can add two matrices?

Comment: can you provide what you have?

Comment: This looks like a command. Please rephrase your question.

Comment: What is this? You think you'll post a question here and someone would answer your homework?

Comment: If this is homework, please have the decency to mention that.

Comment: The answer to this can be found in any C++ tutorial or book, this is basic C++ syntax knowlegde. Not really worth asking here.

Answer (score 1):

From http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/operator-overloading.html#faq-13.1

> The idea is to call functions using
>   the syntax of C++ operators. Such
>   functions can be defined to accept
>   parameters of user-defined types,
>   giving the operators user-defined
>   meaning. For example:
>
> ```
> Matrix add(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y);
> Matrix operator+(const Matrix& x, const Matrix& y);
> Matrix use_add(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b, const Matrix& c)
> {
>   return add(a,add(b,c));
> }
> Matrix use_plus(const Matrix& a, const Matrix& b, const Matrix& c)
> {
>   return a + b + c;
> }
> ```

Also, [this](http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread230114.html) forum thread from lansinwd discusses this in detail

Comment: Note that the code provided is not from the current C++ FAQ, but from what seems to be an older version. (One reason they probably changed the example is that `use_add()` and `use_plus()` aren't exactly identical.)

Answer (score 0):

The idiomatic way to overload operators is the following.

```
struct M {
   ...
   M & operator+=(M const& rhs) {
       loop * 2 to increment
       return this;
   }
};

M operator+(M lhs, M const& rhs) {
    return lhs += rhs;
}
```

But have a look at Blitz++, newmat and boost solutions that eliminate temporary objects thanks to *Expression Templates* -- C++0x's rvalue references will simplify ET solution.

NB: You will prefer to implement op*= in terms of op* instead of the other way around.

Comment: Using `M operator+( M lhs, M const & rhs ) { lhs += rhs; return lhs; }` (as a two liner instead of a one liner) improves the compiler changes of optimizing copies away: it is clear that the returned reference is `lhs`. If you implement it as a one-liner the compiler cannot guess whether the returned reference from `lhs+=rhs` is actually a reference to `lhs` or any other object. (Tests with g++-4.3.3 -O3 show no difference anyway)